# Catch empty list with colander

Tags: python, colander

I'm using `colander` to validate (and deserialize json data) input to some web services.

I would like to add a rule to a colander schema to catch an empty list, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Right now I have the following example, demonstrating a call to the function `f()` with two different sets of data. I would like the later to trigger the `colander.Invalid` exception because of the empty `events` list

```
import colander

def f(data):
    class EventList(colander.SequenceSchema):
        list_item = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int())

    class Schema(colander.MappingSchema):
        txt    = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
        user   = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
        events = EventList()

    try:
        good_data = Schema().deserialize(data)
        print 'looks good'
    except colander.Invalid as e:
        print "man, your data suck"


good_data = {'txt' : 'BINGO',
             'user' : 'mogul',
             'events' : [11, 22, 33]}
f(good_data)

bad_data = {'txt' : 'BOOM',
            'user' : 'mogul',
            'events' : []}
f(bad_data)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using the `colander.Length` validator?

Try to modify your schema with:

```
events = EventList(validator=colander.Length(min=1))
```

For `bad_data` this should raise:

```
Invalid: {'events': u'Shorter than minimum length 1'}
```

Comment: BANG! Spot on. Thanks man! Somewhere down the line I tried almost that, but could not get it just right. Where is the donate beer button when you need it?